# VB.Net not able to connect to SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Button5_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    connetionString = "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=acernis;User ID=root;Password=password"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Currently in my code I have the code above the SQL username and pass are correct as is the DB. I have WAMP running and am using Navicat to make sure I can connect. What is wrong?

Comment: By SQL, do you mean SQL Server?  And what actually happens?  Do you get an error?  Is an exception thrown?  Is so, what is the full message + stack trace of the exception?

Comment: the exception is thrown "Can not open connection ! " How can I get it to display more info?

Comment: That is not the exception.  The exception is `ex`, which you are ignoring. Try adding the exception to the `MsgBox` call: `MsgBox("Can not open connection ! " & ex.ToString)`. Or put a breakpoint on that line and inspect the contents of `ex` while debugging.

Comment: SQL is the query language used for databases.  It is not a database itself. You may well be using MySQL for the database.  If so, you are using the wrong provider objects and wrong connection string.

Comment: If WAMP is an hint then I definitively agree with @Plutonix You have  a MySql database and use the classes and the provider for SqlServer. No way

Comment: There's no possible way he's using WAMP, because the "P" in WAMP refers to PHP... and he's clearly not using PHP. At best, this would be WIMV, but at this point we're not even sure he's building for the web any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using MS SQL server then your issue is with the connection string. try this one :

```
connetionString = "Server=localhost;Database=acernis;User ID=root;Password=password"
```

however if you mean MySQL then you need to change more than just the connectio string

try this:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    connetionString = "Server=localhost;Database=acernis;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Can not open connection Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

to find out what is the connection string that best suites you refer to the website

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button5_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
Dim connetionString As String
Dim cnn As SqlConnection
connetionString = "Server=localhost\<InstanceName>;Initial Catalog=acernis;User ID=root;Password=password"
cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
Try
    if not cnn.State=ConnectionState.Open then cnn.Open()
    MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
    cnn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
End Try
```

End Sub

As per observation, if you are using SQL Server, you need to specify the `<Instance Name>` in `Server` property.

Plus, do not use class `Exception` in catch section, Instead, use specific exceptoin class; in this case, use `SQLException`